# Using count(*) or count(s) on JPA QL

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA Query to get the record count.But it is showing org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException. The Query is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "StudyplanCategory.findCountByStatus", query = "SELECT count(s) FROM StudyplanCategory s WHERE s.status =:status")
```

Please Help.

Comment: I don't use JPA, and it's late, so take for what it is worth: It does something different in "normal SQL" .. In normal SQL `count(col)` will only count the times `col` is not null. However, I suspect that `s.status` *cannot* be null here, especially after the where, so, even if that *were* the difference .. but perhaps `count(status)`, as `s` is not a column, would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select count(*).
See docs
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tipstricks